# I cannot upload any code to my arduino uno

Tags: avrdude, baud-rate

I am using ardunio uno on a windows 10 machine.

I have never been able to upload any code whatsoever.

Every time i get different errors, sometimes it's about com port, sometimes about memory, baud rate and what not.

This time I am getting the following error.

What should I do next?

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries -libraries C:\Users\Jayesh Patel\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:uno -vid-pid=0X2341_0X0043 -ide-version=10805 -build-path C:\Users\JAYESH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_163982 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\JAYESH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_625197 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -verbose C:\Users\Jayesh Patel\Documents\Arduino\sketch_jun21a\sketch_jun21a.ino
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries -libraries C:\Users\Jayesh Patel\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:uno -vid-pid=0X2341_0X0043 -ide-version=10805 -build-path C:\Users\JAYESH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_163982 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\JAYESH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_625197 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -verbose C:\Users\Jayesh Patel\Documents\Arduino\sketch_jun21a\sketch_jun21a.ino
Using board 'uno' from platform in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr
Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr
Detecting libraries used...
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Users\JAYESH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_163982\sketch\sketch_jun21a.ino.cpp" -o "nul"
Generating function prototypes...
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Users\JAYESH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_163982\sketch\sketch_jun21a.ino.cpp" -o "C:\Users\JAYESH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_163982\preproc\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder\ctags\5.8-arduino11/ctags" -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives "C:\Users\JAYESH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_163982\preproc\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
Compiling sketch...
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Users\JAYESH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_163982\sketch\sketch_jun21a.ino.cpp" -o "C:\Users\JAYESH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_163982\sketch\sketch_jun21a.ino.cpp.o"
Compiling libraries...
Compiling core...
Using precompiled core
Linking everything together...
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc" -w -Os -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega328p  -o "C:\Users\JAYESH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_163982/sketch_jun21a.ino.elf" "C:\Users\JAYESH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_163982\sketch\sketch_jun21a.ino.cpp.o" "C:\Users\JAYESH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_163982/..\arduino_cache_625197\core\core_arduino_avr_uno_0c812875ac70eb4a9b385d8fb077f54c.a" "-LC:\Users\JAYESH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_163982" -lm
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0  "C:\Users\JAYESH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_163982/sketch_jun21a.ino.elf" "C:\Users\JAYESH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_163982/sketch_jun21a.ino.eep"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -R .eeprom  "C:\Users\JAYESH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_163982/sketch_jun21a.ino.elf" "C:\Users\JAYESH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_163982/sketch_jun21a.ino.hex"
Sketch uses 1030 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM5 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\JAYESH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_163982/sketch_jun21a.ino.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Jan 17 2017 at 12:00:53
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM5
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\\.\COM5": The semaphore timeout period has expired.



avrdude done.  Thank you.

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
```

Comment: Is it a genuine Arduino or does it have the CH340 USB to serial chip on it?

Comment: how did you choose COM5 serial port?

Comment: What board are you using? Is it a clone? Any chance of a picture?

Answer (score 0):

If you have arduino with ch340 you need to install driver for board.

Comment: The OP seem to have a COM port ready (COM5), which means the driver is already installed.